# Handle Session timeout?

Tags: spring-mvc

How to handle session timeout in spring mvc 3.2 for example after 30 mins it should redirect to index.html.

Tried with interceptor but session time out values specified in web.xml got ignored.

spring-servlet.xml

```
 <mvc:interceptors>   
   <bean class="com.server.utils.AuthenticationTokenInterceptor" />   
   </mvc:interceptors>
```

web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
  </session-config>

 @Override  
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {   
     try  
        {System.out.println("Inside Interceptor");   
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();   
            String authToken = (String) session.getAttribute("userId");   
               System.out.println("Interceptor invoked For Auth token");   
                if(authToken==null || authToken.equals(""))   
                {   
                    System.out.println("Auth Token time Out");   
                 response.sendRedirect(servletContext.getContextPath()+"/login");   
                    return false;   
                }   
                else  
                {   
                 return true;   
                }   
       }catch(Exception ex)   
           {   
           ex.getMessage();   
          response.sendRedirect(servletContext.getContextPath()+"/login");   
              return false;   
           }   
        }   


    @Override  
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,   
          HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,   
        ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {   
   }   

   @Override  
 public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request,   
         HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)   
            throws Exception {   
    }
```

Comment: So what happens exactly? The user makes a request, but the interceptor is not called? Or the server doesn't make a request, but you expect the page to automatically be redirected to /login? What? Describe your scenario.

Comment: The problem is Interceptor is called. but the server doesnot make the request.

Comment: Describe your scenario. The server receives request, but doesn't make requests. I still don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" mode="SQLServer"
    sqlConnectionString="SQLServerConnection" cookieless="false" timeout="60">
   </sessionState>
   <authentication mode="None" />
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="52428800" />
</system.web>
```

- This code put in web.config

```
  $.timeoutDialog
    ({
        timeout: 60 * 60,
        countdown: 20,
        logout_url: '@Url.Action("Logout", "Login")', restart_on_yes: true
    });
```

- This code put in your setup page and use "timeout_dialog.js" it.and others details set in .js file.

  ```
     public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext 
    filterContext)
  {

      if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserID"] == null)
      {
          if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
          {
              filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
              filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
              {
                  JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                  Data = new
                  {
                      Exception="error"
                  }
              };
          }
          else
          {
              filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
              new RouteValueDictionary
              {
                  { "controller", "Login" },
                  { "action", "Login" }
              });
                  //return;
          }
          return;

      }
      base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);            
  }
  ```

  This code put in filter.cs in common class folder file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's better to handle it with plain Java EE than with Spring MVC: The type `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener` is notified of all the changes that happen to the current user session including the timeout. To use an `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener`, you need to register it in `web.xml`:

```
<web-app ...>
        <listener>
        <listener-class>stuff.MySessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

And do your custom logic in your class. The method that handles timeouts is `sessionDestroyed`:

```
package stuff;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

public class MySessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {     

  @Override
  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
  }

  @Override
  public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
      //Your logic goes here
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added sessionEvent.getSession()==null || sessionEvent.getSession().equals("") but i can't redirect ti index.jsp. Do we need to manually invalidate the session?
Every page i need to check the session and then redirect to index page?