# How to handle session timeout in spring mvc?

Tags: spring-mvc

I am working on spring mvc project.

In that i need to handle session time out,

that i can manage by httpsession timout but

how to handle session time out when more then 20 users got logged-in ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290301/handle-session-timeout

Comment: May not be .. what do u mean by session timeout .. Tracking on client side and then making a session time out call ?